# Signal: contact people, or have people contact me, without revealing phone number?

Tags: privacy, anonymity, smartphone, signal

Is it possible to use Signal without revealing my phone number to others?

I'm personally using the Signal app on Android, but of course it applies to all versions, desktop and mobile.

With Telegram for example, I can pick a username and then share that username. And people can contact me with just that username. No phone numbers involved. Is something like that possible with Signal as well? Or do I *have* to give my phone number when asking someone to contact me on Signal?

I realize I have to use my phone at least once to register with Signal itself, and setup an account. But once I've done that, I wish to contact other Signal users, or have other Signal users contact me, without revealing my phone number to them.

Answer (score 5):

The addresses in Signal is the phone number. It's specifically designed to use the phone number to address message, to be a drop in replacement for SMS, and offer opportunistic encryption for text messages and calls between phones.

If this is not fine in your situation, then Signal is (sadly) the wrong system for you. As you say, Telegram (and many others) allow you to use a chosen username.

Comment: It seems you wanted to write "no" without actually writing "no"

Answer (score 4):

**Usenames entered beta in February 2024**

Announcement: https://signal.org/blog/phone-number-privacy-usernames/

Finally!!!

**Related threads on the [de-facto official forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/signal/comments/lipo6z/community_signal_forum_vs_reddit/)**

Consider giving them a like.

This one asks for usernames to be added https://community.signalusers.org/t/username-id-registration-without-phone-number/9800 while still keeping cell phone account creation verification, which seems like exactly what you (and I...) want.

While searching this, I stumbled on the fact that the devs seem to be silently adding usernames to the codebase, which is great!

- https://community.signalusers.org/t/concerns-about-usernames/9468
- https://community.signalusers.org/t/signal-introducing-usernames/9157
- https://community.signalusers.org/t/every-user-can-have-multiple-throwaway-usernames/17397
- https://community.signalusers.org/t/the-great-thing-about-signal-upcoming-usernames/17571

Then there are a billion threads asking for the superset of removing the need for a cell phone completely. This of course then enters anti-spam territory:

- https://community.signalusers.org/t/a-proposal-for-alternative-primary-identifiers/3023
- https://community.signalusers.org/t/remove-the-need-for-a-mobile-phone/1543
- https://community.signalusers.org/t/registering-with-an-email-address/919
- https://community.signalusers.org/t/username-id-registration-without-phone-number/9800
- https://community.signalusers.org/t/have-option-to-set-up-username/8723
- https://community.signalusers.org/t/more-reasons-why-signal-should-ditch-phone-numbers-the-guardian-confirmed-the-identity-of-those-in-the-chat-by-cross-checking-phone-numbers-attached-to-the-signal-accounts/7311
- https://community.signalusers.org/t/why-is-phone-and-phone-number-required/1425
  https://community.signalusers.org/t/what-is-the-technical-reason-that-i-cannot-use-signal-without-a-phone-number-and-that-i-cannot-use-signal-desktop-without-signal-on-my-phone/11400

Answer (score 1):

The way other users can identify you in the Signal-App is solely through your phonenumber. There is no other way you can connect to new contacts.

Like it's said at the [Signal-Website](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/360007459591-Signal-Profiles):

> **What is my Signal Profile?**
>   Your Signal Profile is a name and avatar that you can choose to set up within the app. It will be shown alongside your existing phone number when communicating with other users. Conversations will feel more personal. Group threads will be less confusing.
>
> **Who can see my Signal Profile?**
>   It will be shared with any contacts you have saved in your address book, any people or groups in conversations you create, and any people or groups you explicitly approve.

If it's important for you to dont give your Phonenumber away, Signal isn't the right App to use. But there're some more Apps out there providing almost the same features and using other ways users can identify you e.q. an unique ID.